# How to get hierarchy from multiple values on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, set

I have table RD with only one column:

```
-----
rd_id
-----
3 
2 
6 
7 
8
```

I have table DL with two columns, there is hierarchy on stored on this table:

```
----------------------
dl_id     dl_parent
----------------------
1         2               
2         Null
3         Null
4         6
6         7
7         8
8         Null
```

Now the problem is how to get the hierarchy out from DL table using the member of RD table.
The result will be:

```
--------------
rd_id   dl_id
--------------
3         3

2         2

6         6
6         7
6         8

7         7
8         8

8         8
```

I've been toiling with this problem from Friday and still can't get crack of it.
I know that I can use Common Table Expression to traverse the recursive from one value (like example create one function with input 6 and produce 6,7,8).
but I don't know how to use multiple value (rd_id).

Have some ideas?

Comment: Why do you want the `dl_id`'s with `dl_parent` = `NULL` to be with `dl_id` equal to the same `dl_id` in the result table? Shouldn't be with no parent id? as in the `3  3`, `2  2`, `8   8`

Comment: Hi Gamal, it is business rule from domain expert. since this is business intelligence case that correlate with dimension level and its attributes. But thanks for your feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

This produces the correct results. Data setup:

```
declare @RD table (rd_id int not null)
insert into @RD(rd_id) values
(3),
(2),
(6),
(7),
(8)

declare @DL table (dl_id int not null,dl_parent int null)
insert into @DL(dl_id,dl_parent) values
(1,2),          
(2,Null),
(3,Null),
(4,6),
(6,7),
(7,8),
(8,Null)
```

And the query:

```
;with AllValues as (
    select rd_id,rd_id as dl_id from @RD
    union all
    select rd_id,dl_parent
    from AllValues av
        inner join
        @DL dl
            on
                av.dl_id = dl.dl_id
    where
        dl.dl_parent is not null
)
select * from AllValues
```

Result:

```
rd_id       dl_id
----------- -----------
3           3
2           2
6           6
7           7
8           8
7           8
6           7
6           8
```

Explanation:

In the anchor of the CTE, we simply select `rd_id` from the `@RD` table twice - since your sample implies that every input row should produce an output row with the same value in both columns.

We then join to the `@DL` table for any matching parent rows we can find, based on the second column. If we find a parent, then we produce a new row, substituting the parent value into the second column. This continues until no new rows are produced.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation Damien :)
It gives new perspective on viewing the problem.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use on-the-fly views to create a recursive query like this:

```
with n as (
select dl_id, dl_id as ancestor
from dbo.dl
union all
select np1.dl_id, n.ancestor
from dl as np1 , n
where n.dl_id = np1.dl_parent)
select * from n
where dl_id in (select rd_id from rd)
order by dl_id, ancestor
```

Comment: on-the-fly views, cool... it's new thing for me.
Thank you very much Ecarry :)